# Use an if statement to determine if a pixel is white

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following ahk code that opens my agenda and moves the mouse to a certain position.

```
!o::

 Run, chrome.exe "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/day/2023/7/10" " --new-window "
 MouseMove, -300, 300, 10, R
```

I would like to to include however that he code checks if a mark is checked. If the mark is not checked it should be marked (clicked). So the code I am looking for is a bit like

```
if pixel is not white {
Mouseclick
}
```

I however do not get the latter working. Any thought on what I should do?

Comment: Try [PixelSearch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `PixelSearch` function to find a pixel that is not white. Here is some example code:

```ahk
!o::
 Run, chrome.exe "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/day/2023/7/10" " --new-window "
 MouseMove, -300, 300, 10, R
 PixelSearch, foundX, foundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, 0xFFFFFF
 if ErrorLevel = 0 ; If the pixel is not white
 {
   MouseClick
 }
return
```

This code opens your agenda on Google Calendar and moves the mouse to a certain position. Then it searches for a pixel that is not white. If the pixel is not white, it clicks on it. You can modify my code according to your needs.